# Emacs connect to MySQL (MariaDB) non-interactively

Tags: sql

I am looking into `sql.el`, and I can't find a way to bypass creating comint buffer and setting some global variables in order to connect to the database.

This is less than ideal because I know the credentials, but I don't want to alter global variables which might be used for something else, and there is no way to just create a process and interact with it, or so it seems.

Ideally, I'd like to have a MySQL process, with which I could interact programmatically in an asynchronous way. I.e. the intent is not to let the user write queries, but rather to translate user's input into queries and to execute them as the program sees fit.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found this library: https://github.com/skeeto/emacsql, and so far it seems good, so I'm going to stick with it for now.